# Protection from color vs hexproof

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If I have a prevent all damage from a green source and I am attacked with a creature who is black green and the opponent has paid for its hexproof ability, will I still be protected?

Comment: Can you include the names of the cards that are being used?

Comment: Your title says "protection from color" but the body says "prevent damage from a green source". Those are different things.

Comment: We really need to know the specific cards. If your "prevent all damage from a green source" card uses the word "target" then you will not be protected, as you cannot target a hexproof creature. If the ability on the card is not targeted, then you will be protected. Are you using a [Circle of Protection: Green](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=45206)? That is not targeted.

Comment: @ghoppe That is not necessarily true either. It would depend on the order in which things happened; "prevent the next damage" could resolve before "[cardname] has hexproof" does.

Comment: @GendoIkari A good point, but irrelevant in the case of COP:Green, which is what I suspect we're talking about here. I can't think of any other cards that care about colour of source besides that and the Runes of Protection.

Comment: I would guess COP as well, which does NOT target.

Comment: For reference, there are no cards that specifically prevent damage from a green source *and* target.

Comment: It is very likely that the cards referenced in this question are Reaper of the Wilds and either Circle of Protection: Green or Rune of Protection: Green (which are functionally equivalent for the purpose of this question)

Comment: They dont even relate each other tbh. Hexproof text says that it cant be targeted, and protection doesnt even target.

Answer (score 7):

**The damage is still prevented.**

The scenario you describe seems to be one in which your opponent controls [Reaper of the Wilds](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Reaper%20of%20the%20Wilds) and you control either [Circle of Protection: Green](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Circle%20of%20Protection%3A%20Green) or [Rune of Protection: Green](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Rune%20of%20Protection%3A%20Green). [The rule describing Hexproof](http://mtgsalvation.gamepedia.com/Hexproof), 702.11b, says

> “Hexproof” on a permanent means “This permanent can’t be the target of spells or abilities your opponents control.”

The key word here is "target". Hexproof only prevents spells and abilities from targeting the creature, not from affecting them in general. Targets are described in [rule 114](http://mtgsalvation.gamepedia.com/Targets), and rule 114.1d says

> **An activated ability is targeted if it identifies something it will affect by using the phrase “target [something],”** where the “something” is a phrase that describes an object, player, or zone. The target(s) are chosen as the ability is activated; see rule 602.2b.

Now, if we look at the damage prevention cards, we see that Circle of Protection: Green says

> {1}: The next time a green source of your choice would deal damage to you this turn, prevent that damage.

and Rune of Protection: Green says

> {W}: The next time a green source of your choice would deal damage to you this turn, prevent that damage.

Neither of those uses the word "target", so neither of them targets the source they are affecting. This means that Reaper of the Wilds' Hexproof does not stop them from preventing the damage.